# Senior Moderator Intervention Requested

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My most popular question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash/148042#148042) has suddenly been put on Hold by a bunch of moderators I've never heard of. It has been viewed nearly 10,000 times here and the original on AskUbuntu has been viewed nearly 400,000 times.

Do you care about information that solves people's problems?

Not everyone is running the latest and greatest software. People need answers for older versions as well.

Comment: I should point out that *new* questions on EOL releases are likely to be closed, but questions which were posted when the release was supported are safe. So if you posted about 10.04 when 10.04 was supported, your question will (should) not be deleted.

Comment: Why? Why does it matter at all whether the manufacturer still supports a release? Why doesn't SEU want to help people running older versions on low-performance hardware? Why discriminate against poor people?

Comment: Who says SEU does that? If you have a fresh question on unsupported releases, ask on U&L. Why does it matter? Because the community on AU decided it matters. Please don't raise rubbish straw man arguments that show no understanding of the sites involved.

Answer (score 6):

Your question seems fine to me, but as the close message (and [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) explained, we don't generally want the same question posted on multiple sites, since it leads to duplication of effort. We want to solve people's problems, but we don't want to solve the same problem the same way multiple times; that's just a waste of time and annoys people that search for the problem and find duplicated solutions.

You're apparently worried about your AskUbuntu question getting deleted, but at the moment it [appears to be intact](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197833/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash). Since that question was asked first and answered years ago, this one was closed.

Comment: Thank you for addressing this. However, to not post here until/unless the AskUbuntu posts are deleted, would be too late. The material would be gone and irretrievable unless StackExchange were to create a mechanism for authors to privately access any and all questions, even after "deletion".  The answers and comments would need to remain accessible as well. The same capability would also need to be provided for answerers and commenters.

Comment: @DocSalvager You can already see your deleted questions, it's been that way [for a while](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675), you just need to have a link to them. Double-posting all questions just in case they get deleted from one site isn't really tenable

Comment: Thank You for pointing that out. I had not noticed that. That mitigates most of my concerns, though I would still like to see that mechanism extended to all Q&As instead of just recent, [as Tim has proposed on StackExchange Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492).

Comment: It occurs to me that you may wish to revisit the reasons the closers gave. The first seems clearly inapplicable, and since nearly 12,000 people have viewed it (2000 just since it was put on hold), a lot of folks must be getting something from it. Were I one of those, that first close reason might well challenge my trust in the moderators.